# Accessing mysql database control panel

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I was using wamp server where I could access the `mysql` database throgh `'localhost/phpmyadmin'`. Recently, I've uninstalled the wamp server and installed `mysql server` in my pc. Now, how can I access to my mysql database like `'localhost/phpmyadmin'` when using `wamp`?

Comment: You need a web server to use localhost.

Comment: Do I need to install wamp again?

Comment: I've installed wamp but server can't access to the mysql. I think the passward mismatch. How to change the password?

Comment: @user3782480 see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

WAMP is abbreviation of Windows, Apache2, MySQL and PHP.

phpMyAdmin is a free software tool written in PHP, intended to handle the administration of MySQL over the Web.

`Localhost` refers to a web server(like Apache2 or [nginx](http://nginx.org/) or ...) which PHP can install on it.

So If you want to manage MySQL database with phpMyAdmin. You have to install WAMP :

- [Apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/)
- [PHP](http://www.php.net/)
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)
- [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

*If you want just manage MySQL by phpMyAdmin do above steps.*

---

@Sascha suggested in comments.

You can choose a better solution that doesn't need Apache2 and PHP :

- Install Desktop MySQL managers like [MySQL WorkBench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (Free tool) instead of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: A little extention to this answer. Just in case he won't install a local webserver to run phpMyAdmin. Their are other GUI database mangment solutions like [MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) out their which run without the need of a local webserver.